# Is it possible to use promises for this example?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am basically trying to write a very basic program that will work like this:

```
Enter your name: _
Enter your age: _

Your name is <name> and your age is <age>.
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do something like this in Node without using the `prompt` npm module.

My attempt at this was:

```
import readline from 'readline'

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

rl.question('What is your name? ', (name) => {
  rl.question('What is your age? ', (age) => {
    console.log(`Your name is ${name} and your age is ${age}`)
  })
})
```

However, this nested way of doing it seems weird, is there anyway I can do it without making it nested like this to get the right order?

Comment: In addition consider looking at the docs for `readline`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the recommendation! I was able to shorten the code to what I now have above, I just wanted to ask if there a way to get rid of this nested structure I have to use to get the right order of questions? Is this what promises are for? If so, do you know how I could transform the above to use promises?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

zangw's answer would be sufficient, but I think I can make it clearer:

```
import readline from 'readline'

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

function askName() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    rl.question('What is your name? ', (name) => { resolve(name) })
  })
}

function askAge(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    rl.question('What is your age? ', (age) => { resolve([name, age]) })
  })
}

function outputEverything([name, age]) {
  console.log(`Your name is ${name} and your age is ${age}`)
}

askName().then(askAge).then(outputEverything)
```

if you don't care about wether it ask both questions sequentially, you could do:

```
//the other two stay the same, but we don't need the name or the arrays now
function askAge() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    rl.question('What is your age? ', (age) => { resolve(age) })
  })
}

Promise.all([askName, askAge]).then(outputEverything)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example with [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

```
var readline = require('readline');
var Q = require('q');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var q1 = function () {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    rl.question('What is your name? ', (name) => {
        defer.resolve(name);
    }); 

    return defer.promise;
};

q1().then(function(name) {
    rl.question('What is your age? ', (age) => {
        console.log(`Your name is ${name} and your age is ${age}`)
    });
});
```

Or with simple `Promise`

```
function question1() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        rl.question('What is your name? ', (name) => {
            resolve(name);
        });         
    });

};

question1().then(function(name) {
    rl.question('What is your age? ', (age) => {
        console.log(`Your name is ${name} and your age is ${age}`)
    });    
});
```

Answer (score -5):

There is a way to do it without promises.

```
rl.question('What is your name? ', getUserName);

function getUserName (name) {
    rl.question('What is your age? ', getUserAge(name));  
}

function getUserAge (name) {
    return function (age) {
        console.log(`Your name is ${name} and your age is ${age}`)
    }
}
```

See, no nesting but properly refactored functions. You can and should do the same with api's that return promises. Anonymous functions is a nice feature of the language but that doesn't mean you must use it for everything.

Comment: but the question was how to do it WITH promises. all you've done is split the code into named functions. this is not an answer

Comment: @Emobe This is an answer attempting to solve the XY problem. The question can be read as "how do I avoid nesting" and this answer reminds people that promises are not the only way of avoiding nesting. This was asked a long time ago when promises was not part of the standard language (indeed it was not even part of node.js back then). People have obsessed too much on callback nesting hell that they forgot that non-callback structured for loops, if..else and switch blocks also had nesting hell but was solved by splitting code into named functions..

Comment: .. indeed now that promises are more common it is still worth reminding people that good coding practice to split your code to manageable functions because now we start to see people write promise nesting hell. I was trying to remind people that nesting hell is not a "feature" of async code. People tried to find excuses to hate on async code completely forgetting good coding practices.